# How to manage category name before blog post slug title in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, url, seo

I have seen many blogs and tried but I want something another.

The blog post URL I've tried -

```
localhost/post/how-to-include-category-title-in-blog
```

same for

```
localhost/post/how-to-create-php-script
```

There is the common thing is post page -----

I need that - 
Suppose that I have three categories in my blog - PHP, HTML, CSS

I create posts in every category - 
So the URL should be -

```
localhost/php/what-is-php
```

for CSS posts -

```
localhost/css/what-is-css
```

for HTML posts

```
localhost/html/what-is-html
```

Syntax like -

```
localhost/category_name/post_title
```

The category should be related to the post.

I need to remove the post and want it dynamic.

```
localhost/post/how-to-create-php-script
```

the post is a page in the blog. I want it to remove and manage according to these URL -

```
localhost/php/what-is-php 


localhost/css/what-is-css 



localhost/html/what-is-html
```

I am working on PHP core.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get familiar with the Parmalinks page in WP admin. Here is the documentation from WP: https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-permalinks-screen/

For your need you probably want to try a custom permalink config like:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Comment: I am working on PHP core, not WordPress. Kindly share PHP core reference.

Comment: apologies... I did not interpret your question that way initially

Comment: So now what? Help me.